# Can't figure out how to sort by hour (value) with the old x.sort() in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

I'm trying to get the timecode from emails in an hh:mm:ss format and parse out the the hour. Then I put it in a dictionary so it shows how many emails per hour then put that in a list and print it out like so:

```
04 3
06 1
07 1
09 1
10 3
11 6
```

I need it sorted by the hour/value with the old `x.sort()` function for lists. The autograder the course uses doesn't support sorted(). At the moment it seems to be ignoring the .sort() command completely:

```
11 6 
10 3 
15 2
14 4
```

Here's my full code:

```
name = raw_input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)

counts = dict()

for line in handle:
    line = line.rstrip()
    words = line.split()
    if words == [] : continue
    if words[0] != 'From' : continue
    full = words[5:6]
    allitems = ".".join(full)
#    print allitems
    for linee in allitems:
        linee = allitems.rstrip()
#        if linee in counts : continue
        wordss = linee.split(':')
        cutt = wordss[0:1]
        print cutt
    for val in cutt :
        counts[val] = counts.get(val, 0 ) + 1
print counts

lst = list()
for hour, frequency in counts.items() :
    newtup = (hour, frequency)
    lst.append(newtup)

lst.sort
print lst
for howr, freq in lst:
    print howr, freq
```

What's going wrong here?

Comment: `lst.sort` doesn't call the function, just refers to it. You always need to use `()` if you want a function to be properly called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `sort()` method, as of now, you are just getting the reference to the `list.sort` function, without doing anything with it, Example -

```
lst.sort()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name = raw_input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)

counts = dict()

for line in handle:
    line = line.rstrip()
    wrds = line.split()
    if words == [] : continue
    if words[0] != 'From' : continue
    full = words[5:6]
    allitems = ".".join(full)
#    print allitems
    for linee in allitems:
        linee = allitems.rstrip()
#        if linee in counts : continue
        wordss = linee.split(':')
        cutt = wordss[0:1]
        #print cutt
    for val in cutt :
        counts[val] = counts.get(val, 0 ) + 1
#print counts

lst = list()
for hour, frequency in counts.items() :
    newtup = (hour, frequency)
    lst.append(newtup)

lst.sort()
#print lst
for howr, freq in lst:
    print howr, freq


    python
```